# Best practice to declare different user roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to declare different user roles on my site and I was wondering what is the best practice to do it in Rails? For now I have two options:

**OPTION 1:**

I create table Users and declare one string column where I can store names of user roles (SuperAdmin, Admin, Coach, Player)

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "role"
end
```

Inside User class I save the values like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ROLES = %w[SuperAdmin, Admin, Player, Coach]
end
```

**OPTION 2:**

I create a separate table only for roles. Inside Users table I have integer column for storage of role_id:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "role_id"
end

create_table "roles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "role_name"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

What would be a better option when if we take search speed, addition of new roles and future maintenance into the consideration?

Comment: Would depend on how complex this will become. If you ever intend to add tables with permissions, then the table approach is better (same for multiple roles per user). If you will just hard code a few places that ask for a specific role, then approach one will be less work.

Comment: or u can use gem rolify

Answer (score 3):

Basic variant:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class CreateRolesUsersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :roles_users, id: false do |t|
     t.integer :user_id
     t.integer :role_id
    end
  end
end
```

Here's why: you don't want `has_many` with roles, cause you won't be able to associate the same role with different users. It is a typical HABTM relationship. Yes, later it can become a performance problem, since it can be pretty hard to fetch all roles with associated records for every user. Then you will look into other variants for optimization: bitmaps, intensive caching or something else.

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Create an other table to store the role is an over engineered solution :)

Use the gem **cancan** is a good approach, you need just to add a field to the user model. 
With cancan you can even assign multiple roles to a user and store it into a single integer column using a bitmask.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best way is to use a standard `has_many` `belongs_to` relationship between a `User` and `Role` model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :role

   before_create :set_role

   def set_role
       role = self.role_id
       role_id = "0" unless defined?(role)
   end 
end

#app/models/role.rb
Class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
end

users
id | role_id | name | created_at | updated_at

roles 
id | name | created_at | updated_at
```

This will allow you to associate users to a specific role, and continue to add / adapt the roles as required

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit that part after `before_create`? `def role` should be `def set_role` or? Why do we need that inside `Role` class? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :) All fixed